# ASP.NET MVC Instability

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Got a slightly odd one here.

We have an MVC site that is experiencing some instability.  Once a week for the last couple of weeks the site has gone down.  We have found that all we need to do to bring the site back up again is 'touch' the web config file (i.e. open it and save it, with no changes).  This brings the site back to life immediately and keeps it alive for another week or so.

The site has custom error pages set up so we can't actually see the error that is being thrown, and there is nothing appearing in the IIS logs.

It looks like some kind of memory leak problem, however .NET garbage collector should manage this, right?

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Pat

Comment: I think you should provide more info. Try to log the exception with Elmah or similar tool. The problem might be caused be some code executed inside your application or external library rather than ASP.NET MVC itself

Comment: It looks there is a problem with your application pool or the whole IIS , since it's fixed with touching web.config. Can you provide more details ?

Comment: No, the .NET garbage collector can't be guaranteed to clean up - memory usage for an IIS application pool can creep upwards. Is the site on your own server or using 3rd party hosting?

Comment: While you're waiting to see if any of the suggestions solved your problem, consider up voting the ones that were helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You should have some kind of logging so that you can see what error you get. I usually use [elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/). That will give you the full error message and stack trace. It's pretty hard to say what the problem is without knowing the error. But it can be a memory leak of some kind. Do you use a lot of unmanaged code? The garbage collector can't handle everything.

Answer (score 2):

Touching the web.config forces recompilation and refreshes the app pool. My guess is something is knocking out your app pool, whatever it is will be in the event logs, i suggest you check there.